# How can I find Windows 10 dependent APIs from my C++ code and ensure it runs on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, compilation, msbuild, windows-11

I have a C++ VS project which compiles and runs fine on Windows 10. By static analysis or by some trick, I want to migrate and compile the code to Window 11. How do I find the windows 10 dependent APIs and libraries from my code ?

Comment: Windows has _excellent_ backwards compatibility. If your code runs on Windows 10, it will almost certainly run on Windows 11. The main exception would be bugs in your code which don't trigger in Windows 10 today - but the next security update of Windows 10 could expose those bugs. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Have you tried just running your software on Windows 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trick. Just install Windows 11 SDK and do the build.
[See here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/)

Answer (score 1):

The details on the areas you should focus on testing for Windows 11 are in the [Compatibility cookbook for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/windows-11/testing-guidelines).

> Note you didn't state what version(s) of Windows 10 you support already, but if you've been keeping up with the regular releases, you should be in good shape.